# Active Record like functionality on array instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to write a module that provides active record like functionality on an array instance variable.

Examples of its use would be

```
x = Container.new
x.include(ContainerModule)
x.elements << Element.new
x.elements.find id

module ContainerModule
   def initialize(*args)
     @elements = []
     class << @elements
        def <<(element)
          #do something with the Container...
          super(element)         
        end

        def find(id)
          #find an element using the Container's id
          self
          #=> #<Array..>  but I need #<Container..>
        end
     end
     super(*args)
  end
end
```

The problem is that I need the Container object within these methods. Any reference to self will return the Array, not the Container object.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
class Container
  attr_accessor :elements

  def initialize
    @elements = ContainerElements.new
  end
end

class ContainerElements < Array

  def find_by_id(id)
    self.find {|g| g.id == id }
  end

end
```

So i create a container-class, and a ContainerElements that inherits from Array, with an added (specific) find_by_id method. 
If you really want to call it `find` you need to `alias` it.

Example code would be:

```
class ElemWithId
  attr_accessor :id
  def initialize(value)
    @id = value
  end
end

cc = Container.new
cc.elements << ElemWithId.new(1)
cc.elements << ElemWithId.new(5)

puts "elements = #{cc.elements} "
puts "Finding: #{cc.elements.find_by_id(5)} "
```

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach may be to work with the [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html) class, which has operations like finding by id already.  Particularly, the [fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002849) method may help you out.

Comment: A hash really isn't an option. It needs to act like an array since the code base used it as such.

Comment: I may be misinterpreting what it is you need, but couldn't you just pass hash_object.values() to things that need to treat with it as an array?